# Manually allow ping.exe through the Windows 7 firewall

Tags: windows-7, firewall, ping

To improve my feeling of security I recently switched my Windows 7 firewall to block all outbound connections. The only thing I can't seem to get to work is ping.exe.

I tried by creating custom rules to allow everything through from cmd.exe to ping.exe (both versions in the system32 and SysWOW64), but I had no luck so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The option that should be changed is *protocol*, not *program*. The steps are:

1. Select all programs
2. Select ICMPv4 from protocol
3. Apply for any IP address.

Comment: But that would essentially open up my entire outbound connection again. The main reason I set it up this way was to prevent unwanted programs from constantly contacting all kinds of services.

Comment: No it will only open up ICMP protocol connections. Actually that protocol is almost same as Ping program, no another programs use it.

Comment: Learned something today. Didn't knew the exact specifications of that protocol. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. Good to hear the solution works.

Comment: After step (2) you should Select "Specific ICMP types" and select only "Echo Request" to avoid opening up all ICMP types. I edited the answer adding the step (3).

Comment: You can also do it in PowerShell: `New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "Allow outbound ICMPv4 echo request" -Direction Outbound -Protocol ICMPv4 -IcmpType 8 -Action Allow`